# What are the worlds oldest market indexes?

Tags: stock-markets, market-indexes

I recently noticed that the S&P500 index has recorded daily price entries for over 90 years:

> https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC?p=%5EGSPC

the first recorded day being the `1st December 1927`.

I wonder, do other indexes exist which have a comparably long recorded history? 
If so, which ones?

Comment: The only thing that I could find was wage and price controls in the ancient world: https://mises.org/library/wage-and-price-controls-ancient-world . Or the bible does list merchant commodities of Babylon in Revelation.

Comment: @SSpring That's pretty cool! :) Though, unfortunately, these indexes don't exist (any more).

Answer (score 1):

The oldest stock index that’s still calculated and used is the [Dow Jones Transportation Average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dow_Jones_Transportation_Average), which was established in 1884.

Comment: Unfortunately, its historical data only seems to start on `1st October 1928` on yahoo finance: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EDJT?p=%5EDJT Is there some source that provides daily recorded price data starting from `1884`, as is visible in the plot on wikipedia?